# JSON.NET Adding to JArray

Tags: json, json.net

I've got a json array that I want to add to, then write the content to a file. I have no problem adding the content to the array, but writing to file using the JsonSerializer.Serialize method gives me the exception:

ArgumentException:
Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.

This occurs on the last line of my code below. "jSerializer.Serialize(o.CreateWriter(), o);"

JSON

```
{
"ArrayToManipulate":
[
    {
        "Name":"Value"
    },
    {
        "Name":"value"
    }
]
}
```

Code to manipulate the JSON Objects

```
JContainer o = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(new JsonTextReader(reader));
JArray x = (JArray)o["ArrayToManipulate"];
ContentObject newObject = new ContentObject(){Name="Value"};
JToken tokenToAdd = JToken.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newObject, Formatting.Indented));
x.Add(tokenToAdd);
JsonSerializer jSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
jSerializer.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter());
jSerializer.Serialize(o.CreateWriter(), o);
```

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The writer you get by calling `JContainer.CreateWriter` doesn't write to a file as you want - it is a writer to write to the container itself. You need something like the code below - create a "regular" text writer based on a file, then a `JsonWriter` based on that.

```
const string JSON = "{\"ArrayToManipulate\":[{\"Name\":\"Value\"},{\"Name\":\"value\"}]}";
var reader = new StringReader(JSON);
JContainer o = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(new JsonTextReader(reader));
JArray x = (JArray)o["ArrayToManipulate"];
ContentObject newObject = new ContentObject() { Name = "Value" };
JToken tokenToAdd = JToken.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newObject, Formatting.Indented));
x.Add(tokenToAdd);
JsonSerializer jSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
jSerializer.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter());
using (var w = File.CreateText(@"C:\temp\a.json"))
{
    using (var jw = new JsonTextWriter(w))
    {
        jSerializer.Serialize(jw, o);
    }
}
```

Comment: And how **DE-Serialize" from a _a.json file_ ?